# Error SQL : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have created two tables in my database

```
CREATE TABLE ratables (
            id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
            ratableKey varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            created_at timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        ) AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE ratings (
            id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
            ratable_id int(11) NOT NULL,
            ip_address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            rating int(11) NOT NULL,
            timestamp timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            PRIMARY KEY (id), 
            CONSTRAINT rabid_ratings_fk FOREIGN KEY (ratable_id) REFERENCES
            ratables(id)
        ) AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

When I tried to insert

```
INSERT INTO ratings(ratable_id, ip_address, rating) VALUES ('9', 'ip_adresse', 'rating');
```

it gave me this error

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (bd_pagespro.ratings, CONSTRAINT rabid_ratings_fk FOREIGN KEY (ratable_id) REFERENCES ratables(id))
```

Please Help!

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the non-standard syntax used.

Comment: You need a record in table ratables with id = 9.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: all the DBs have non-standard syntax somewhere.

Comment: @siride yes of course and that helps identifying the DBMS being used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: the implication and tone of your statement was that MySQL is somehow special for having non-standard syntax. It would have been enough to just say that the syntax looks like the MySQL dialect, as indeed any RDBMS could be identified in such a fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means there is no row in your table ratables with id='9'.

As I don't know what database you use I cannot be sure that it's not merely a type issue. '9' may not be an int, hence the error.

Comment: The non-standard backticks instead of double quotes strong suggest it's MySQL

Comment: Thanks a lot! actually it was the part of the code wich is doing the insert par that did't work, so eventually it  wasnt a raw with an id=9 !
So thaks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Turn this off by adding this before the insert command :

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

then set it back after your inserts:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Just beware and make sure you know what you are doing. Definitely make sure to insert the appropriate data into the foreign key afterward.

Comment: This would no doubt be improved if you mentioned a few of the potential problems to avoid.